# pm2: command not found in ec2 when running script file

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-ec2, deployment, gitlab

after deploying node.js project using gitlab CICD successfully when try to execute script.sh file which is in side project folder it shows

**./script.sh: line 3: pm2: command not found**

I want to **restart pm2** server after deploying node.js file

[image: error while executing script file from gitlab]

now , if I run this script.sh file after ssh into my ec2 from terminal it execute successfully.

[image: run script.sh file from terminal]

here is my script.sh file

[image: script.sh file]

Help me to solve this ,

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: did you install pm2 globally? `npm i pm2 -g`, as it seem that directory you showed in CICD pipeline is seemed different than the one you showed after `ssh`. or try to add the path in the script instead of ssh argument, so the script will look like this `cd /home/ubuntu/backend_path; pm2 restart server.js`

Comment: Hii @Adiii , directory path is same in ssh & terminal also & I have tried this path in script file
cd /home/ubuntu/backend_path; pm2 restart server.js

but It did't work

problem is not the path because if finds script file on both from terminal & gitlab runner also but it not recognize pm2 commands

Comment: did you install pm2 globally?

Comment: yes I have installed pm2 globally

Comment: and the user that ssh is ubuntu from gitlib?

Comment: yes it's ubuntu (Gitlab runner)

Comment: this script (script.sh) is running in ec2 environment which is also Ubuntu

Comment: okay got it, so let try to run this command from your machine so it clear one thing that problem with gitlib or with ec2 `ssh -i yourkey.pem ubuntu@server_IP 'cd elearning-backed && ./script.sh'`

Comment: hey @Adiii when run this command which you gave from terminal it shows 

./script.sh: line 3: pm2: command not found

Comment: So its not something that can be solve it pipline level, better to debug using above command

Comment: @Adiii I have find solution , please see the answer and many thanks for your time & guidance :)

Comment: Yes and I told you in the comment that is the user same that do ssh 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so , after tried many possibles ways I have find that first go into your root in ec2 using **sudo su** and then install npm & pm2 into root directory.

after this you can able to run pm2 command from script file.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you can add the below commands and check, it's worked for me.

**sudo ln -s "$(which pm2)" /usr/bin/pm2**

I worked in AWS EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since EC2 start script run as root user and, this is a way you can run the pm2 worker for a different user from root. It worked perfectly on my ec2 machine.

cd /
su ubuntu -c "PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.3.0/bin pm2 start app.js"